# How do iterate through all sub vectors in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Lets say i have a class Foo. It contains a vector of type Foo. How can write a loop to iterate through the vector in foo and continually iterate through the sub vectors until we reach a level where on of the vectors is empty

```
class Foo
{
  Foo();
  std::vector<Foo> foos;
}
```

I can do this to iterate it through, but how can i iterate through the vectors in the foo objects inside the original vector recursively until i reach a level that the vector is empty?

```
Foo f;
if( !f->foos.empty() )
{

   std::vector<Foo>::const_iterator itr;

   for ( itr = f.foos.begin(); itr!=f.foos.end(); ++itr )
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: If Foo has a vector of Foos, then you'll get a stack overflow due to the recursive nature there. Are you sure it's not a vector of Bar ?

Comment: @ChristopherBales is right, this DataStructure actually implements a Tree...

Comment: The posted code is illegal, and doesn't compile with g++ and the usual options (including `-D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC`, which turns a lot of undefined behavior into hard errors).

Comment: Yes the vector is the same type as the object and it does compile fine for me on VS2012.

Comment: @Bullsfan127 That's because it's undefined behavior, and MSVC doesn't implement any concept checking.  By chance, it seems to work.  Until the next revision of the compiler.  (It was the intent of the committee at one time to require a compile time error for this, but the tools necessary to implement it didn't get finished in time to make it into this version of the standard.  G++ does implement a preliminary version of them, however.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo();
    std::vector<Foo> foos;

    void iterate()
    {
        std::vector<Foo>::const_iterator itr;

        for ( itr = foos.begin(); itr!=foos.end(); ++itr )
        {
            // do stuff  breadth-first
            (*itr).iterate();
            // do stuff  depth-first
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1:  Clever, but recursion rarely has a place in production-level code.

Comment: @JohnDibling Totally depends on the requirements. Actually, it's quite often a good (production-level) solution.

Comment: Where your comments are, these points aren't visited in an BFS and DFS order. Both are DFS due to the nature of recursion. Recursion *is* DFS. The second point in your code is just *after* visiting child-nodes, also called "backtracking". BFS usually uses a queue instead of a stack (which is implicitly used when implementing it using recursion).

Comment: I wouldn't say that recursion "rarely" has a place in production code.  You would certainly want to apply recursion appropriately, but it is not in itself an error nor is it necessarily less correct than a non-recursion alternative.

Comment: well, recursion is avoidable using a stack<Foo> and a while loop... We can write it here if OP/anyone cares :)

Comment: @JohnDibling Recursion is the only appropriate solution here, and it widely used in production code for similar problems.

Comment: I think @Dibling means using function level recursion. e.g. actually recursively calling the same function. Recursive algorithms that use stacks and queues in the same function are still recursive algorithms. But it is old style thinking. Function calling has so much processor support today that I bet it doesn't really matter any more.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista If the solution is recursion, then it is plain stupid to do it by hand, when the language supports it implicitly.

Comment: In ye olden days, when compilers didn't optimized recursive function calls away, and when processors didn't have hardware support for super fast function calling, manually doing your recursion using a function local stack made a lot of sense. Even today, you can't be sure the compiler will optimize away recursive function calls unless the function is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Use a queue:

```
std::deque<Foo> q;
q.push_back(f);
while (!q.empty()) {
    Foo curr = q.back();

    typedef std::vector<Foo>::iterator iter;
    iter end = curr.foos.end();
    for(iter it = curr.foos.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
        if(!it->empty()) {
            q.push_back(*it);
            continue;
        }
        // do stuff with *it
    }

    q.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: The recursive solution is simpler.

Comment: @JamesKanze Recursion normally make for simpler solution but there is always a risk of the program crashing if you don't have stack space.

Comment: And there's a risk of the program crashing if you don't have the necessary heap.  And there's a risk of the program crashing if you make a programming error, which is more likely if the solution you chose is more complicated.

Comment: There is way less stack space than heap space. A recursive function with large data structures will explode.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Foo` objects form a tree data structure. You can represent any path from root to some node as a `std::stack<Foo*>` to keep track of your position in the tree. Using this idea and a depth-first search, you can do your operation of visiting all of the `Foo` objects without using recursion.